# "Error: couldn't find adapter method" when using Microsoft Graph Typescript SDK

Tags: typescript, vue.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to use the Microsoft Graph Typescript SDK in a Vue Application that runs in an Outlook Task Pane. I followed the documentation. However, I run into an error when trying to get my own user via graph.

Using this code, I try to authenticate myself and get my own user as a test.

```
    import { ClientSecretCredential } from "@azure/identity";
    import { AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider } from "@microsoft/kiota-authentication-azure";
    import { createGraphServiceClient, GraphRequestAdapter } from "@microsoft/msgraph-sdk";
    import "@microsoft/msgraph-sdk-users";

    /*...*/

    const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        "...", //tenant
        "...", //client-id
        "...", //client-secret
    );
    const authProvider = new AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider(credential);
    const requestAdapter = new GraphRequestAdapter(authProvider);
    const graphServiceClient = createGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);
    const myUser = await graphServiceClient.users.get();
    console.log(myUser);
```

The users.get() fails with the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: couldn't find adapter method
    at send (apiClientProxifier.ts:180:13)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (apiClientProxifier.ts:227:26)
    at MyPage.vue:34:49
    at runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2872:88
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:192:19)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:199:17)
    at hook.__weh.hook.__weh (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2852:19)
    at flushPostFlushCbs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:367:40)
    at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:405:5)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Check if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/typescript?tabs=aad